# Intercept python stdout and convert to single line

Tags: python, logging, stdout

So, I have some services running and the whatever is printed in the console is scraped by datadog agents to show in the Datadog UI. The problem is sometimes when there is an unexpected error the stacktrace is multiline and that shows up as different logs in datadog. Is there any way to automatically intercept any stdout and convert that to multiline ?

I could always try except everything and take care of that in my logger but try excepting every piece of code is probably not ideal ?

Comment: What if you change stderr to write to some file?

Comment: How is this interception supposed to tell which "mult-lines" it should remove \n and turn into a single line, and which to pass on as single lines?

Comment: Well ideally it always removes multiline. I was hoping for an interceptor when a new message comes in and every new message should be turned into a single line

Comment: stderr to a file is not an option. The entire prod is based on scraping from stdout

Answer (score 2):

@Lenormju [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67933023/5054458) works perfectly!

I would add, if you have a logger configured to output json then you may want to change the `print` statement to `logger.error`.

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def single_line_excepthook(ex_type, ex_value, ex_traceback):
  logger.error(
    "%s\n%s", repr(ex_value), "|".join(traceback.format_tb(ex_traceback))
  )
```

output

```
{"asctime": "2021-10-16 22:06:02,310", "levelname": "ERROR", "name": "test_file", "filename": "test_file.py", "lineno": 27, "dd.service": null, "dd.env": null, "dd.version": null, "dd.trace_id": null, "dd.span_id": null,
"message": "ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')\n  File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>\n|  File \"/code/test_file.py\", line 126, in consume\n    1 / 0\n"}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to change the [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) :

> This function prints out a given traceback and exception to sys.stderr.
>
> When an exception is raised and uncaught, the interpreter calls sys.excepthook with three arguments, the exception class, exception instance, and a traceback object. In an interactive session this happens just before control is returned to the prompt; in a Python program this happens just before the program exits. The handling of such top-level exceptions can be customized by assigning another three-argument function to sys.excepthook.

Default behavior is to print on multiple lines :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C://PycharmProjects/stackoverflow/67925591.py", line 15, in <module>
    throw()
  File "C://PycharmProjects/stackoverflow/67925591.py", line 10, in throw
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

But using this code :

```py
import sys
import traceback


def single_line_excepthook(ex_type, ex_value, ex_traceback):
    print(repr(ex_value) + "|".join(traceback.format_tb(ex_traceback)).replace("\n", ""), file=sys.stderr)


def throw():
    1/0


sys.excepthook = single_line_excepthook

throw()
```

I get a single line output :

```
ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',)  File "C://PycharmProjects/stackoverflow/67925591.py", line 15, in <module>    throw()|  File "C://PycharmProjects/stackoverflow/67925591.py", line 10, in throw    1/0
```